# How are the points for attributes used?

Tags: character-creation, savage-worlds

This is my first time creating a character in *Savage Worlds*, so I'm confused on how the attribute points work. I have the core rule book and I have played before, but it was with pre-generated characters. We have five points to spend with it stating that all the attributes start at a d4. That part makes sense, but what are the points used for with this?

It also states that we have 15 points to use for skills. How does that work as well?

Comment: What is *Savage Worlds (Gaslight Edition)*? Are you referring to the Savage Worlds version of the third party setting *[Gaslight Victorian Fantasy](http://www.rpgnow.com/m/product/224188)*?

Comment: Yes. Another person answered the question which made sense. But thank you for responding.

Comment: The question and answer apply to all Savage Worlds settings, so I edited your question to remove the part about Gaslight. If you don’t like my changes, feel free to revert it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The attributes (Agility, Smarts, Strength, Spirit and Vigor) all start at d4. During character creation, you can use five points to raise your attributes by one die type at a time: from d4 to d6, from d6 to d8, and so on up to d12.

The skills start at *untrained*, which is rolled as d4 with a -2 penalty. You can use the 15 skill points to train your skills. Advancing a skill from untrained to d4 costs one point. After that, you can advance a skill by one die type up to d12 for one skill point per die type, as long as the skill's die type does not surpass its linked attribute (eg. Agility for Shooting). To advance a skill above its linked attribute, you must spend two points per die type.

You can get additional skill points or increase your attribute die further by choosing Hindrances during character creation, and will gain more later as your character gains experience.

Comment: @Hannah If this answers your question, you can accept the answer by clicking the checkbox to the left of the answer.